# Error when compiling cannont access class

Tags: java

Trying to compilie this AuctionClientMain.java  and this is the error I get and can't figur it out:

> AuctionClientMain.java:16: cannot access AuctionClient
>       bad class file: .\AuctionClient.class
>       class file contains wrong class: Assignment.AuctionClient
>       Please remove or make sure it appears in the correct subdirectory of the classpath.
>                       AuctionClient a = new AuctionClient(args[0],args[1],port);

I have included AuctionClientMain.java

```
import Auction.*;
import java.io.*;

public class AuctionClientMain
{
    //Create the client
    public static void main (String args[]) throws IOException
    {
        if(args.length!=3)
        {
            throw new RuntimeException ("Syntax: java AuctionClient <name> <serverhost> <port>");
        }

        //Convert port taken in as string to an integer
        int port = Integer.parseInt(args[2]);
        AuctionClient a = new AuctionClient(args[0],args[1],port);

    }

}
```

And the Auction Client

```
package Auction;

import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;

public class AuctionClient
{

    public AuctionGui gui;

    private Socket socket;
    private DataInputStream dataIn;
    private DataOutputStream dataOut;

    //Auction Client constructor  String name used as identifier for each client to allow server to pick the winning bidder
    public AuctionClient(String name,String server, int port)
    {
        //Create a new gui
        gui = new AuctionGui("Bidomatic 5000");
        //Add the key listener to the input field
        gui.input.addKeyListener (new EnterListener(this,gui));
        //Add the exit listener to the window
        gui.addWindowListener(new ExitListener(this));

        try
        {
            //Create a new socket with server name and port number provided
            socket = new Socket(server, port);
            //Create new data input stream
            dataIn = new DataInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
            //Create new data outpit stream
            dataOut = new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());

            dataOut.writeUTF(name);
              while (true) 
              {
                gui.output.append("\n"+dataIn.readUTF());
            }
      } 
      catch (Exception e)   
      {
         e.printStackTrace();
      }

    }



    //Send bid to output stream
    public void sentBid(String bid)
    {
        try
        {
            //Write bid out
            dataOut.writeUTF(bid);
        }

        catch(IOException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    public void disconnect()
    {
        try
        {
            socket.close();
        }

        catch(IOException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `Assignment.AuctionClient` -- where did it get 'Assignment' from?

Answer (score 0):

Your `AuctionClientMain` class seems to be in the default package. The `AuctionClient` class is in package `Auction`. The .class file for `AuctionClient` needs to be in a subdirectory named `Auction` relative to `AuctionClientMain`.

Alternatively, put `AuctionClient` in the default package or put `AuctionClientMain` in package `Auction`.

On a side note, Java conventions are that package names are all lower case. It would be better to use `package auction;` instead of `package Auction;`.

Answer (score -1):

Because AuctionClient is in the Auction pacakge, the compiler expects to find the Java source file in a directroy called Auction.